# Rmarkdown chunk with xtable() stopped rendering LaTeX table

Tags: xtable, rmarkdown

I have a data analysis Rmarkdown file that I will use to knit a .pdf results section for my thesis. I had beautiful working LaTeX table code when I knit a pdf together in Rstudio using the knit button this morning. However, I've seemed to have broken it. I am consistently getting the following error & output: `error in as.string(y) : Cannot coerce argument to a string`, `Calls: <Anonymous> ... print -> print.xtable -> +.string -> paste -> as.string`

My dataframe `class(df)` reads `[1] "data.table" "data.frame"` and I am getting the error after calling `sum_table` in my example.

What I've tried:

- Removing my additions to xtable() and print() functions one by one back to an extremely simple form.
- Running the code line by line instead of as a Rmd chunk.
- Adding display argument to xtable() [xtable documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xtable/versions/1.8-4/topics/xtable)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled xtable and R. I am running MacOS 10.12.6 (older computer), R 3.6.3, and Rstudio 1.2.5033.
- added `booktabs=TRUE` arguement to print() [xtable example](https://gist.github.com/pschmied/9691642)

Any ideas about this error or troubleshooting?

Simple Rmd chunk example:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
indent: true
---
# Rmd chunk settings
# results = 'asis' to output LaTex code that is recognized as code
{R Summary_Table, echo = FALSE, results = 'asis'}

library(knitr)
library(tinytex)
library(xtable)
options(xtable.timestamp = FALSE)

df <- data.frame(A = c(1:10),
                 B = c(11:20),
                 C = c(21:30))

sum_table <- xtable(df)
sum_table # Error thrown here "as.string(y) : Cannot coerce argument to a string"
print.xtable(sum_table)
# try another print function
print(sum_table)
# try adding booktabs argument
print(sum_table, booktabs = TRUE)

#Tried adding display argument to xtable(), extra for xtable's automatic
# number column. Thought maybe num variables couldn't be turned into a string? 
sum_table2 <- xtable(df, display = c("s","f","f","f"))
sum_table2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I reproduced your error but after updating all my R packages it disappeared.

Comment: Updating packages (face palm)! Just updated all of my packages, but the data.table package is the only that is throwing errors. However, I don't think my table code uses any data.table functions. My table code is still giving me the same `error in as.string(y) : Cannot coerce argument to a string`.

Comment: Looks like it might be a mac instillation problem?  [link](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/news/index.html)

Comment: Can you execute this: `rm(list=ls()) library(xtable) data(tli) xtable(tli[1:10, ])`? If you are still getting the `error in as.string` you still have a package that needs to be updated. Are you compiling binaries when an updated version is available? This error is not related to `data.table`.

Comment: Ok, tried that code, and got the same error. I am compiling binaries when I update packages (I think based on this [Rstuido Community discussion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/meaning-of-common-message-when-install-a-package-there-are-binary-versions-available-but-the-source-versions-are-later/2431) ). Updating data.table is giving me the `There are binary versions available but the source versions are later` message. This means that the binary for the update isn't available for Mac yet? Next step try Rtools? This is all new territory for me.

Comment: On a whim tried running the table code without doing anything additional, and it worked perfectly, producing LaTeX table code. I am thoroughly stumped, but thrilled. As soon as I added `options(xtable.timestamp=F)` before the table code, the same error showed up. Even when I commented out the options code, the table still threw the error. It seems like the options code is turning a switch. When I quit and restart my Rproject the table code works again.